# Is a static constructor initializer possible?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following classes.  (From a game but vastly simplified.)

combat.h:

```
class Combat {
public:
    Combat();
    Combat(int health, int offense, int defense);
    virtual ~Combat();
    int  attack();
    int  defend();
    int  health() const;
    void setHealth(int health);

private:
   struct CombatImpl;
   std::unique_ptr<CombatImpl> _impl;
};
```

combat.cc:

```
struct Combat::CombatImpl {
CombatImpl();
    CombatImpl(int health, int offense, int defense);
    ~CombatImpl()=default;

    int         _health;
    int         _offense;
    int         _defense;
};

Combat::Combat(int health, int offense, int defense) :
    _impl { new Combat::CombatImpl(health, offense, defense) } {
}

Combat::~Combat()=default;

int Combat::attack() {
    int hits = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < _impl->_offense; i++ ) {
        if (rand() % 6 == 5) {
            hits++;
        }
    }

    return hits;
}

int Combat::defend() {
    int parries = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < _impl->_defense; i++ ) {
        if (rand() % 6 == 5) {
            parries++;
        }
    }

    return parries;
}

int Combat::health() const {
    return _impl->_health;
}

void Combat::setHealth(int health) {
    _impl->_health += health;
}

Combat::CombatImpl::CombatImpl(int health, int offense, int defense) {
    _health  = health;
    _offense = offense;
    _defense = defense;
}
```

monster.h:

```
class Monster: public Combat {
public:
    Monster(int health, int offense, int defense);
    virtual ~Monster();
}
```

monster.cc:

```
Monster::Monster(int health, int offense, int defense)
    : Combat(health, offense, defense) {}

Monster::~Monster()=default;
```

player.h:

```
class Player : public Combat {
public:
    Player();
    virtual ~Player();

private:
    struct PlayerImpl;
    static PlayerImpl _impl;
};
```

player.cc:

```
struct Player::PlayerImpl {
    PlayerImpl()=default;
    ~PlayerImpl()=default;
} Player::_impl;

Player::Player() : Combat(17, 1, 1) {
}

Player::~Player()=default;
```

...and finally, a test program that uses them:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
#include "monster.h"
#include "player.h"

static Monster monster(3, 1, 1);

void fight() {
    Player player;
    int damage = monster.attack();
    damage -= player.defend();

    if ( damage > 0 ) {
        player.setHealth(-damage);
    }

    if ( player.health() < 1 ) {
        return;
    }

    damage = player.attack();
    damage -= monster.defend();

    if ( damage > 0 ) {
       monster.setHealth(-damage);
    }

    if ( monster.health() < 1 ) {
        return;
    }

}

int main() {
    Player player;

    srand(time(NULL));

    while (player.health() > 0 && monster.health() > 0) {
        fight();

        printf("player health = %d    monster health = %d\n", player.health(),
            monster.health());
    }
}
```

If you run this program you will see that it doesn't work.  The Monsters health is reduced as it should be, but the Players health is stuck at its initial value.  The reason I think it is happening is this;  Player only has static data (encapsulated in PlayerImpl _impl)  This is so I can have one global Player object which I can call from different functions in my code.  (the monostate pattern.)  But its base class Combat is dynamic.  So what is going on is that each time I create Player player; in fight() I am actually getting a new Combat where Combat::_health is the default value.  When player goes out of scope, any changes to _health are lost.  In monster, this isn't a problem because Monster objects have dynamic data too.  Ideally I'd be able to say

```
 class Player : public static Combat {
```

to mean make static this particular Combat only but that is a syntax error.  Is there another way of doing that?  Or have I painted myself into a corner?

Comment: **Far** too much code.  Please simplify this some more!

Comment: Why do you create many player *objects*? An object (of class type) is an *instance* of a class. By using this method, creating many player objects that all shall refer the one player, what your code indicates contradicts your intent / what's going on. Either pass a player object (reference) to every function or use a free / static `getPlayer` function (that returns a `Player&`).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorry about the length of the example code.  The real thing is much longer and this is the barest minimum I thought I could cut it down to and still provide enough context for my question.

Comment: @DyP The idea of the monostate pattern (which I am using successfully elsewhere in the code.) is to avoid a global singleton which I'm told is a bad design practice.  Is there no way I can mix in another class and have it be included in the "staticness" of Player?  Or is this one of the cases where a "best practice" should not be blindly apllied?

Comment: @Jaldhar: If everyone can create a `Player` object that accesses the same data... how is that *any different* from a global singleton object that you have to access by calling a certain function? The problem with the global singleton is not the fact that it's a global, rather than a static member somewhere. It's the fact that the data is accessible from *everywhere*.

Comment: @DyP speaks wisdom. Player is not a global singleton, yet you want one of its subclasses to so. Even if you get it to work this is confusing. Either the static global singleton pattern for player is good, or a full dynamic one is also a good design. But mixing is at odds with the design of the language. Don't fight the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you haven't really thought about your encapsulation hierarchy. Player deriving from combat doesn't make a lot of sense, and your implementation confusion (and this problem) backs that up. You've fallen afoul of the fact that C++ gives us multiple-inheritance instead of interfaces, because I believe what you're trying to describe is that Player has a Combat interface.

A common approach to clean this kind of problem us is to use forwarder/bridge/delegate/trait/accessor classes, in this case perhaps "Combatant" or "CombatHandler" or "CombatEntity" - all depending how you want the inheritance to read - whose sole purpose is to help you traverse the encapsulation graph; in this case, from an entity to the encapsulation of the fight functionality for that class of entity.

These intermediate classes are mean't to be simple, limited to interconnect logic. Don't put any actual functionality in it; try to keep all members const.

```
class Combatant {
public:
    Combatant() {}
    virtual const Combat* Combat() const = 0; // so combat is technically our impl
    virtual Combat* Combat() = 0;
    // keep this interface light, it's primarily an accessor interface.
    virtual bool CanFight() const { return (Combat() != nullptr); }
    virtual bool CanFight(Combatant* opponent_) const {
        return (opponent_ != nullptr && CanFight() && opponent_->CanFight());
    }
};

class PassiveEntity() : Combatant {
   ...
   const Combat* Combat() const { return nullptr; }
   Combat* Comat() { return nullptr; }
}

class Player : public Combatant {
public:
    virtual const Combat* Combat() const override {
       // if you HAVE to use a static, something like this.
       return &s_playerCombatImpl;
    }
    virtual Combat* Combat() override {
       // but really it should be a member so it can be stateful.
       return &m_combat;
    }
    ...
};

class Monster : public Combatant {
    ...
};

class Corpse : public PassiveEntity {
    ...
};
```

The second thing you should refactor is whatever is causing you to call global functions without parameters instead of calling

```
monster.fight(player);
//or
player.fight(monster);
```

I suspect this is because you're trying to implement frames and haven't yet encapsulated that, so the frame doesn't know who the participants are and you're forcing it through the use of globals.

Take another look at your original and review how the use of statics was forcing your hand further down the line: hoisting Combat specifics and awareness into the Player class, further breaking your encapsulation.

That's not to say that singletons or globals have to be avoided at all costs, just make sure you check yourself -- did you really mean to say that this information is visible AND modifiable by any class, including "PrawnShriveller" and "MP3Player", as well as the global function "WhenIdleFormatHardDriveCatchFireOrDoOtherThings()"?